# if() handles booleans in a strange way

Tags: marklogic, serverside-javascript

We are talking server side java script here on the MarkLogic platform.
Now I am confused:

```
// query

function testBoolean(){
 return false
}

if(testBoolean()){'true'} else {'false'}
```

gives the string "false" as testBoolean() is of type Boolean.

Now my own function returns also a boolean but I need an explicit comparison before `if()` figures it out...

```
function userExists(userName) {
    // check if user exists in security database
    var data = {userName : userName}
    var options = {
               "database" : xdmp.securityDatabase()
                };
    var res = xdmp.eval("declareUpdate(); var sec = require('/MarkLogic/security.xqy'); sec.userExists(userName)",
                                data,options);
    return res
};

// make sure result is actually aboolean
// xdmp.type(userExists('scc-user-1'))

if(userExists('notextistinguser')){ 'true' } else {'false'}
```

gives the string "true" ???

The user 'notextistinguser' does not exist(duhhh), the function returns a type boolean of value 'false' and still this passes as true. I tried looking at the 'different-transaction' option.

When I compare explicitly in need to cast the false to a string?

```
userExists('notextistinguser')=='false'
```

So what type is my custom function now? It reports boolean but acts as a string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your last line to be:

```
if(fn.boolean(userExists('notextistinguser'))){ 'true' } else {'false'}
```

or change the return on your function to be :

```
return fn.boolean(res)
```

That returns the correct result now.

---

`fn.boolean()` will convert that into an actual JavaScript boolean for you.

Here are some results from testing:

```
typeof(userExists('notextistinguser')) //Returns Object

typeof(fn.boolean(userExists('notextistinguser'))) //Returns Boolean
```

https://docs.marklogic.com/fn.boolean

Answer (score 1):

[`xdmp.eval()`](http://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp.eval) *always* returns a [`ValueIterator`](http://developer.marklogic.com/learn/sjs/concepts#iterators). `ValueIterator` is the core of how MarkLogic does lazy evaluation. A non-`null` `ValueIterator` will always be truthy, just like any non-`null` (non-Boolean) object. If you know your eval returns a single value (or you just want the first one), use `.next().value` on your `ValueIterator` instance (or, more correctly, [`fn.head(vi)`](http://docs.marklogic.com/fn.head) in MarkLogic >=8.0-5). For example,

```
'use strict';
var itr = xdmp.eval('false;'); // Returns a ValueIterator 
                               // instance that iterates 
                               // over a singleton boolean value
itr instanceof ValueIterator;  // true
1 === itr.count;               // true, singleton
false !== itr && true !== itr; // true, ValueIterators aren’t booleans       
false === fn.boolean(itr);     // true, fn.boolean coerces 
                               // singleton ValueIterator 
                               // instances to their effective 
                               // boolean values
false === itr.next().value;    // true
```

Note that `fn.boolean()` will coerce a singleton value to its effective boolean, according to the rules of XQuery, which defines its semantics.

Take a look at my [`applyAs()` wrapper function](https://gist.github.com/jmakeig/0a331823ad9a458167f6) for an example of using first-class functions to make using `xdmp.eval()` a little simpler.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that when your function returns `res` that `res` is not an actual Boolean of `false` or any value that would be coerced into being false. So, instead a 'truthy' value is returned and coerced into the Boolean true.

You'll need to verify what your function is returning and force a conversion to a Boolean as needed.